# Shutdown azure cloud service

Tags: azure

I am running an azure cloud service with two roles, I want to shut it down so it will stop billing me.  I would rather not delete it because I don't want to have to recreate it in the future, just turn it back on.  Is this possible, or is the only way to stop the billing to delete the cloud service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, shutting down an Azure Cloud Service (assuming you're talking about Web/Worker role) will not stop billing. To stop billing, you would need to delete the deployment.